# How does main() function compare to other functions in C?

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

The documentation is:

> In C, the "main" function is treated the same as every function, it has a return type (and in some cases accepts inputs via parameters). The only difference is that the main function is "called" by the operating system when the user runs the program. Thus the main function is always the first code executed when a program starts.

But when I run

```
int main() {
    printf("%d", square(3));
    return 0;
}

int square(int n) {
    int sq = n * n;
    return sq;
}
```

the program prints 9.
So does the main() function get executed only after all the other functions or is it special in a different way?

Comment: `main` is called first, and is calling other functions. So eventually the called functions *terminate* before `main` terminates.

Comment: What "all the other functions"? The only function that is called automatically is `main`.

Comment: It's misleading to say that main is called "first". ONLY main is ever called by the OS. All other functions are never called unless they are called by main(), or by some function called by main(), etc.

Comment: I'm uncertain from where that quotation was drawn (certainly not the C language standard), but it seems reasonably accurate, and it seems also to address the question.  So what is it you really want to know, and / or what about the behavior you observe makes you question the quoted description?

Comment: Wanted to understand the order of execution.

Comment: This question makes a lot more sense if you imagine OP being Python user introduced to compiled languages for the first time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order is this:

1. OS calls `main()`
2. `main()` calls `square(3)`.
3. `square(3)` calculates the result `9` and returns it.
4. `main()` calls `printf("%d", 9)`
5. `printf()` prints `9` on the terminal and returns the number of characters printed (1).
6. `main()` returns 0 to the OS.

Comment: Not quite true.  The call to `printf()` does not output the '9' to the terminal. Rather, `printf()` outputs the '9' to the `stdout` buffer.   Since the data being output does not end with a '\n' the data sits in the `stdout` buffer until the `main()` function exits.  Then the contents of the `stdout` buffer are passed on to the terminal.

Comment: That's a level of detail that I don't think is really important when discussing the order of function calls.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between getting defined and getting called.

`main()` is the one function directly called by the runtime to execute the program. Some others might be called in initializers for global variables, or some other special circumstances, but let's ignore those, especially as they are irrelevant to your case.

And all the others get called someway from there, directly or indirectly. Or they are simply dead code.

There is another difference for `main()` since C99: `return 0;` is implicit for it.

As an aside, ramp up the warning level, all those functions called before / without being declared are errors.

Answer (score 3):

This code

```
int main() {
    printf("%d", square(3));
    return 0;
}

int square(int n) {
    int sq = n * n;
    return sq;
}
```

relies on the obsolescent feature of *implicit function declarations*, because there is no declaration of the name `square` before its usage in `main`.  This feature was removed from the C standard in its 1999 revision.  All the most commonly used C compilers still honor it (with warnings) for backward compatibility's sake, but actually *using* it is bad style and can hide bugs.  You should write this program with an explicit "forward declaration" of `square` above `main`:

```
int square(int n);

int main(void)
{
/* remainder of program as you have it */
```

(Not putting anything at all between the argument parentheses of a function declaration or definition is *also* an obsolescent feature.  To declare or define a function that takes no arguments you have to say `(void)`.)

(In C, for historical reasons, preferred style is to put the opening curly brace of a function definition on its own line, even if all other opening braces are "cuddled" onto the same line as the `if`, `for`, etc.)

Having said that, the function square is executed because, in main, it is called:

```
int main() {
    printf("%d", square(3));
                 ^^^^^^
    return 0;
}
```

That is, first `main` gets control and then inside `main` the function `square` is called.  If `main` did not call `square`, or call a function that calls it, `square` would never be executed.

The difference between the function `main` and any other function is that in a host environment the function `main` contains the entry point to the program that is it gets the control first. And the function `main` may be defined without the return statement though its return type is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I have thought of this question in general. my starting point was "where I should handle dynamic allocation i.e malloc? in the main or the library function?

I lastly figured out that, if we do not distinguish between the main and other functions, then it is not a question. So, it is up to the taste of programmer to divide into seperate functions or not.

However, talking about differences between main vs other functions by the example of malloc-free stuff, we allocate memory in the function but we free it in the main. This is might be  obvious ofcourse!. if we use free in the function before return, what we are returning right!

Comment: Your answer doesn't really answer the question. The user simply wants to know what the flow of a basic program is. Your answer will probably just confuse them even more (especially by mentioning "the algorithm").

Answer (score 0):

> How does `main()` function compare to other functions in C?

Saying that `main` is "treated the same as every function" is somewhat incomplete. The `main` function is *mostly* like any other function in C, but it does have one key distinction, and two key differences.

Distinction: `main` is special in that it is the *entry point*: the one function that is automatically called by the execution environment to get your program up and running.

Difference #1: Unlike every other function in C, `main` has *two* signatures.  It can either be `int main(void)` (that is, accepting no arguments), or `int main (int, char **)`.

Difference #2: If you write a `main` function without a `return` statement, it is compiled as if you had written `return 0;` at the end.

An ordinary function, by contrast, must have exactly one signature, agreed on once and for all by the function definition, all function declarations, and all callers.  In an ordinary function, if it's declared as returning anything other than `void`, and if control flow "falls off the end" without an explicit `return` statement, you're heading into undefined behavior territory.